# import realm make the apps force close

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm

I'm a newbie to learning react-native and I'm making a note app, but I'm getting struggle with my realm because it keeps force closing when I try to import the realm here is my folder photo before I start:

[This is my contents of the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA5bx.png)
[This is the rest of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylkh8.png)

okay, I have a problem with the realm at AddNoteScreen.js:

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Icon} from 'react-native-elements';
import realm from '../../store/realm';

const saveNote = newNote => {
  const allData = realm.objects('Note');
  const dataLength = allData.length;
  let lastIdFromRealm = 0;
  if (dataLength !== 0) {
    lastIdFromRealm = allData[dataLength - 1].id;
  }
  if (newNote !== '') {
    realm.write(() => {
      realm.create('Note', {
        id: dataLength === 0 ? 1 : lastIdFromRealm + 1,
        note: newNote,
        date: new Date().toISOString(),
      });
    });
    // console.log('Successfully save your note!');
    alert('Successfully save your note!');
    const data = realm.objects('Note');
    console.log(data);
  } else {
    alert('Empty note!');
  }
};

const AddNoteScreen = props => {
  const [tempNote, setTempNote] = useState('');

  const {navigation} = props;
  return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Create</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
          <Icon
            name="check"
            type="font-awesome-5"
            size={18}
            onPress={() => saveNote(tempNote)}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.date}>Date</Text>
      <TextInput
        multiline
        placeholder="Write here"
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={text => setTempNote(text)}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

//this is my style

export default AddNoteScreen;
```

okay, that

```
import realm from '../../store/realm';
```

that I take to AddNoteScreen.js is from the index.js inside the store/realm folder and the content in my index.js is like this:

```
import Realm from 'realm';
import {NoteSchema} from './NoteSchema';
const realm = new Realm({
  schema: [NoteSchema],
});
export default realm;
```

besides, inside the store/realm folder, I have the file named NoteSchema.js and its content is like this:

```
export const NoteSchema = {
  name: 'Note',
  properties: {
    id: 'int',
    note: 'string',
    date: 'string',
  },
  primaryKey: 'id',
};
```

here are my dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.11",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.14.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "realm": "^11.3.1"
  },
```

the problem is, if I run the `import realm from '../../store/realm'` this note application immediately exits without any obvious errors.

I have tried the solution like uninstalling the realm that I used which is realm 11.3.1 and I tried to install the recommended one in @11.0.0-rc.1 and also tried the @11.0.0-rc.2 but the result is the same. It still forces close

I want my application not to force close again, what do I need to do?

Comment: `Realm` seems incompatible with `react-native-reanimated` v2 (see [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/3713)). Also, hermes engine may cause crash (see another post [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/3837)).

Comment: Realm seem to crash on 0.71 version https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/5259